# I can't connect my phone with android studio using wifi to test my app

Tags: android

Recently I was working on an app and I used my phone to test it , I was connecting it via Wi-Fi and then test The App.

But now when I want to connect my phone it keeps giving me this message "Connecting to device. this takes up to 2 minutes" and in the end an error occurred connecting device.
Here is some screenshots:

PS: I tried also connecting my phone using the pairing code but still the same issue
[image][image]

Comment: It sometimes does not work as expected on some devices, on my Galaxy Flip 3, it works once and no more, so use just usb.

Comment: I have a a galaxy A30 S i just had this problem today morning

Answer (score 0):

You do not have you use wifi connection. From your phone's settings open developer options. Then click the developer options menu and active " usb-debugging "

Finally, connect your phone via USB to the computer. Then at the bottom menu select your phone as a running device.

Comment: But is there a way to fix this issues and use WIFI to test my app ????

Comment: Yes, you can. Open the developer options menu and active "wi-fi debugging".

Comment: I did that, my phone is paired with android studio but it can't connect